# How can I improvise matlab code from GLCM to CLCM(Color Level Co occurrence Matrix) for feature extraction in texture analysis?

Tags: image-processing

Currently I am doing my project on SKIN DISEASE DIAGNOSIS USING TEXTURE ANALYSIS in IMAGE PROCESSING domain.In this project,the histopathological image of diseased skin image is given as input and the name of the disease,details about the particular disease related to that image should be displayed as output.For feature extraction of such image,GLCM is not useful(as the input is a histopathological image).So,CLCM(Color Level Co occurrence Matrix) works well for such input.Can anyone help me with the matlab code for CLCM?[image: Example of histopathological image]

I am using MATLAB R2013a for this project.Is this okay or Do i need to change the version for better results?